# Reading file line by line in C++ skipping some lines

Tags: c++, string, input, getline

I have the following type of input text file

```
28306.5934893134
Const for C
0.086628745225
Const for D
1226.12828874073
Const for F
6.60731462829
Const for G
-14694.9395750279
Const for J
273245702.243239
Const for K
5563100.12791444
```

I want to read line by line. I'm currently using ifstream and getline that looks like this:

```
correl>>const_h;
cout<<const_h;


std::getline(correl,line_avoid);
correl>>C1;
cout<<C1<<endl;


std::getline(correl,line_avoid);
correl>>C2;
cout<<C2<<endl;

std::getline(correl,line_avoid);
correl>>C3;
cout<<C3<<endl;

std::getline(correl,line_avoid);
correl>>C4;
cout<<C4<<endl;

std::getline(correl,line_avoid);
correl>>C5;
cout<<C5<<endl;

std::getline(correl,line_avoid);
correl>>C6;
cout<<C6<<endl;
```

The first value is getting read, but not the others. How do I read the values only and skip the comments in the input file?

Comment: Consider shortening your example, as the error seems to occur after reading the first few lines.

Comment: Two minor things: (1) it might be better to say *"discarding"* rather than *"skipping"* as you *have* to read them one way or another (simply to find the start of the next line...); and (2) once you realize that you might ask yourself *"How do I distinguish the comments from the good stuff and can I make the process automatic once I have read in any particular line?"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do e.g `correl>>C1;` the newline is left in the stream, so the next `getline` gets that newline and the following `correl>>C2;` attempts to fetch from the line you want to ignore.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. The first is to use `getline` for both lines, ignore the line you want to ignore, and use `istringstream` for the other to extract the value:

```
std::istringstream is;

std::getline(correl, line_avoid);
std::getline(correl, line_keep);
is.str(line_keep);
is >> C1;
cout << C1 << endl;
```

The other way is to skip to, and over, the newline after you read your value:

```
std::getline(correl, line_avoid);
correl >> C1;
correl.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
cout << C1 << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need special declaration to use '.ignore' function? Which stl lib does this command exist? I am getting errors 'numeric_limits' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @user1705329 `ignore` is part of the `std::basic_istream` class, so nothing is needed for that. For [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) you need the `<limits>` header file.

Answer (score 1):

The following, simpler code should do the trick:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

std::ifstream infile("data.txt");

for (std::string l1, l2; std::getline(infile, l1) && std::getline(infile, l2); )
{
    std::cout << "Data: " << l1 << std::endl;
}
```

(If you want to parse the line as a number, you can use `double d = std::stod(l1);` in C++11, or use any of the other conversion methods.)

Comment: For bonus points (read: an upvote) please explain what the OP did wrong

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I've done that a million times in the past; not tonight :-S Just look at any duplicate for a comment of mine.